Ml Kit text recognition date
I develop an app in Kotlin for android to recognize date on a live camera. I use ML KIT text recognition V2 from Google to achieve this.
It works perfectly on simple date for differents formats (dd/MM/yyyy, MM-yyyy, etc...).
The problem is when the date is dotted like this :
dotted date
I think it's due to the ML kit model and how it was trained but to you have sugestions solving this problem. Maybe a custom model or a function to use.
code :
@OptIn(ExperimentalGetImage::class) private fun processImageProxy(
        textRecognition: TextRecognizer,
        imageProxy: ImageProxy,
        regex: Regex
    ){
        imageProxy.image?.let { image ->
            val inputImage =
                InputImage.fromMediaImage(
                    image,
                    imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
                )
            textRecognition.process(inputImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener { text ->
                    regex.find(text.text)?.let {
                        val validFormat = findDateFormat(it.value)
                        if(validFormat != null){
                            var date = it.value
                            if(date.isNotEmpty()){
                                val format = when(validFormat){
                                    ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_YYYY_SLASH -> "dd/MM/yyyy"
                                    ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_SLASH -> {
                                        date = "$date/${LocalDate.now().year}"
                                        "dd/MM/yyyy"
                                    }
                                    ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.MM_YYYY_SLASH -> {
                                        date = "01/$date"
                                        "dd/MM/yyyy"
                                    }
                                    ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_YYYY_UNDERSCORE -> "dd_MM_yyyy"
                                    ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_UNDERSCORE -> {
                                        date = "${date}_${LocalDate.now().year}"
                                        "dd_MM_yyyy"
                                    }
                                    ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.MM_YYYY_UNDERSCORE -> {
                                        date = "01_$date"
                                        "dd_MM_yyyy"
                                    }
                                    ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_YYYY_SCORE -> "dd-MM-yyyy"
                                    ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_SCORE -> {
                                        date = "$date-${LocalDate.now().year}"
                                        "dd-MM-yyyy"
                                    }
                                    ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.MM_YYYY_SCORE -> {
                                        date = "01-$date"
                                        "dd-MM-yyyy"
                                    }
                                }
                                try{
                                    val dateParsed = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format))
                                    val foundDate = ExpirationDateViewModel.ExpirationDate(dateParsed,validFormat,false)
                                    if(dateParsed.isAfter(LocalDate.now())){
                                        if(foundDate != expirationDateViewModel.date.value){
                                            expirationDateViewModel.modifyExpirationDate(foundDate)
                                            vibrate()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }catch (_: Exception){ }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    imageProxy.close()
                }.addOnCompleteListener {
                    imageProxy.image?.close()
                    imageProxy.close()
                }
        }
    }



private fun findDateFormat(date : String) : ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat?{
        val formats = arrayOf(
            "\\b\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\b" to ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_YYYY_SLASH,
            "\\b\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}\\b" to ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_SLASH,
            "\\b\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\b" to ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.MM_YYYY_SLASH,
            "\\b\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4}\\b" to ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_YYYY_SCORE,
            "\\b\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}\\b" to ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_SCORE,
            "\\b\\d{1,2}-\\d{4}\\b" to ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.MM_YYYY_SCORE,
            "\\b\\d{1,2}_\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\b" to ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_YYYY_UNDERSCORE,
            "\\b\\d{1,2}_\\d{1,2}\\b" to ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.DD_MM_UNDERSCORE,
            "\\b\\d{1,2}_\\d{4}\\b" to ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat.MM_YYYY_UNDERSCORE
        )

        var returnFormat : ExpirationDateViewModel.DateFormat? = null
        for ((regex, format) in formats) {
            if (date.matches(Regex(regex))) {
                returnFormat = format
            }
        }
        return returnFormat
    }

Thank's!
I scan date with different formats using ML KIT on Kotlin, but when the date is dotted it doesn't work.
